# Android Calendar API

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to design an android app that will fetch calendar events for multiple businesses. I need each to have their own secure calendar. The app will fetch the calendars for each, when called.

I would also like to use notifications, if possible.

What is a good way to do this? Can I just use Google Calendar and the app can use the Google calendar api?

If I build the data in MySQL on my webserver, then I might be able to use notifications?

Ideas?

One last thing.... If I do use notifications, then the app will need to remain running in the background on the device, correct?